# C#, Access Search through multiple tables for a Serial Number

Tags: c#, sql

I have 1 Access database with 2 tables. I am using a C# winforms application. I have Serial Number fields in each table but nothing is related. I have a form with a text field and a button to search for a Serial Number, then will return results into a datagrid on the form. Currently I can simply search 1 table. What I would like to do is type in the number, hit the button and return the value after searching both tables. I would rather do this without a union because somehow I need to set the table name in a text box when the results return.

```
private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
        OleDbDataAdapter db = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtSerial.Text))
        {
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                command.Connection = connection;
                command.Transaction = transaction;
                command.Parameters.Add("@searchSerial", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = txtSerial.Text;
                string searchFB = "SELECT (SerialNumber) FROM Inventory WHERE SerialNumber = @searchSerial";
                command.CommandText = searchFB;

                db.Fill(dt);
                dgResults.DataSource = dt;
                connection.Close();
            }

            catch (OleDbException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: *"Currently I can simply search 1 table."* So search one table, and if it's not found search the other. What's the question here?

Comment: That's what I cant figure out. I tried using the results of Rows.Count, DataReader.Hasrows....no success.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include what you've tried and what was wrong with the results you got. If you do `var count = db.Fill(dt);`, `count` should be the number of records added to the `DataTable`, at least according to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/905keexk(v=vs.110).aspx).